# How to get php7 to load extensions via apache

Tags: php, apache, mysqli, freebsd

I can get php to load the extensions via the command line, but NOT via apache.

php70 is installed on FreeBSD (10.3-RELEASE-p20)

running from the command line: php -m 
shows **all** the modules that are installed in the extensions directory. 
php.ini file is /usr/local/etc/php.ini and the extensions are defined in /usr/local/lib/php/20151012

HOWEVER via apache (using mod_php), I can't get the extensions to run:

```
<?php
print_r(php_ini_loaded_file());
echo "<br>";
print_r(get_loaded_extensions());
?>
<?php
```

Shows the same .ini file (/usr/local/etc/php.ini)
but only lists a few modules (
[0] => Core [1] => date [2] => libxml [3] => pcre [4] => Reflection 
[5] => SPL [6] => standard [7] => mysqlnd [8] => apache2handler)

AND the error log shows the extensions can't be read:

- PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
  '/usr/local/lib/php/20151012/mysqli.so' -
  /usr/local/lib/php/20151012/mysqli.so: Undefined symbol
  "executor_globals" in Unknown on line 0
- PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
  '/usr/local/lib/php/20151012/hash.so' -
  /usr/local/lib/php/20151012/hash.so: Undefined symbol
  "file_globals" in Unknown on line 0

This is for all the files located in 2015102 directory

Those files do exist and the permissions on all the directories is drwxr-xr-x
all the files have r+x

Using Apache/2.4.18 (FreeBSD)

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: check that also `php-fmp -m` contain all the modules

Comment: it indeed shows all the modules.  Does that mean I should learn about migrating from mod_php to php-fmp ?

Answer (score 0):

Might you possibly have updated to PHP70 and associated extensions without updating mod_php, which isn't included in the PHP70 port / package.

In any case, my first suggestion would be to recompile PHP70* and mod_php, then restart Apache.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  For completeness, I have installed php70, php70_extensions, ports/www/mod_php70 (after the install of php70); still no luck, still stuck (w/apache restart).  I moved to php-fmp (and it works).  Still it would be nice to know if a solution exists.